# Liquibase failing on BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, liquibase

When I run the Liquibase on BigQuery, I get the below error:

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE
> DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = false, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED
> = NULL WHERE ID = 1: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver Error executing query job. Message: Table "DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK" must be
> qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

I have seen posts saying I should drop the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tbl, but the problem is, this is the first time I am running the migration and it has not created any of the tables I wanted.

Testing the BigQuery connection is fine, but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by add the below under the `<configuration>....</configuration>`

```
<changelogSchemaName>dataset-name-goes-here</changelogSchemaName>
```